# NSURLRequest failing after previous request success

Tags: objective-c

I am relatively new to Objective-C but getting there. I am building a small app that accesses a database via NSURLRequests. Upon loading the view, within viewDidLoad, I execute a request to get some data....

```
NSString *content = [@"http:/localhost/detailAPI.php?token=" stringByAppendingString:token];
content = [content stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(content);
taskData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:content]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Within connection didReceiveData, I can process the response and put the information on the screen, release taskData. Part of the view is a textfield where the user can add a comment. I then send the comment to the server for insertion into the database using a similar structure.

```
NSString *updateURL = @"http://localhost/updateAPI.php?update=task&token=";
updateURL =[updateURL stringByAppendingString:token];
updateURL =[updateURL stringByAppendingString:@"&taskname='"];
updateURL =[updateURL stringByAppendingString:taskName.text];
updateURL =[updateURL stringByAppendingString:@"'&comment='"];
updateURL =[updateURL stringByAppendingString:TaskComments.text];
updateURL =[updateURL stringByAppendingString:@"'"];
taskData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:updateURL]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

The first thing that my PHP scripts do is get the data and create an 'activity' record. In the first request, I can see the activity record, the data is returned and all is good with the world. With the second request, I see nothing. The app does nothing. I can cancel out and return the main display. I can return to this view and the new comment is not there.

I have tried releasing the connection at the end of the didReceiveData processing, no change. I have tried force starting the connection in the second query with startImmediately set to YES. I have spent about 3 hours on Google and AppleDev and am no wiser. I know this is going to be a simple solution, however I just cannot see it.

Thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: are you sure that the php script is OK? try make the 2nd connection first to see if it's an issue with the ordering. Also try to implement  the other connection delegate methods for more debug info.

Comment: can you post the methods from `NSURLConnectionDelegate`?

Comment: Alin, just prior to hitting the NSURLRequest, I put the URL to NSLog. I have literally copied and pasted this into a browser and received a valid response from the script. My scripts have all potential failures covered (that I know of) that return a response that my app is designed to cope with. From looking at the server, the script is not being hit at all.

Comment: Told you it would be something simple. Thank you babbidi. In testing this out to find a previous bug, I had commented out the connection release in connectionDidFinishingLoading. Too many line of code, not enough coffee! However, now I get bad URL (null), so something else is wrong.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In testing this out to find a previous bug, I had commented out the connection release in connectionDidFinishingLoading.